# Signing of a binary matrix to a totally unimodular matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, matroids, total-unimodularity

I have the following binary matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& 1& 0 \\
 0& 1& 1& 1\\
 1& 0& 1& 1\\
 1& 1& 0& 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

**Definition:** Signing a matrix means means changing some $1$s to $-1$s.

**Question.** Is there a signing of the matrix such that it becomes totally unimodular over $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

For example
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&1&0\\ 0&-1&-1&1
\\ -1&0&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&0&1
\end {array} \right] 
$$
(and many others)

EDIT: For the new question, the answer is no.  There are only $2^{12}$ possibilities, and it's easy to write a program to check all of them.

Comment: Sub matrix with determinant = 2 found
    [-1     1;
    -1    -1]

Comment: You changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a four element matrix. All four element matrices except for one (U2,4) are regular so there will be a signing that makes it totally unimodular. Maybe you are asking a more general question? "Given any binary matrix is there a signing that will make it totally unimodular." In this case better to ask whether or not a given binary matrix is regular. Tutte gave a good algorithm for determining if a binary matrix is graphic. Together with  Seymour's decomposition of binary matrices we can determine if a binary matrix is regular.

Comment: The term 'regular matrix' is used for non singular matrices as well. Is it true that a binary matrix which is non singular,can be signed to get a regular(i.e totally unimodular) matrix?